# Docker build failing with "project file not found" errors

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I have a couple dotnet core console apps I'm using to mess around with docker on Linux containers.

I right clicked on my `server` project and clicked added Docker Support.

It auto generated the Dockerfile and when running this I get project reference errors.

Running the `docker build -t myserver .` command throws error

`Step 7/13 : RUN dotnet restore ./dockertest.sln
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/NuGet.targets(239,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/src/client/client.csproj" was not found. [/dockertest.sln]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/NuGet.targets(239,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/src/server/server.csproj" was not found. [/dockertest.sln]`

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0-2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY src/server/server.csproj src/server/
COPY src/client/client.csproj src/client/
RUN dotnet restore src/server/server.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/src/server
RUN dotnet build server.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish server.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "server.dll"]
```

UPDATE:
Just noticed this in the output window when saving a change to my dockerfile
`A non-critical error occurred while getting containers ready.  Your project will continue to function normally.  The error was: 
Unable to resolve the NuGet package dependency paths for the project C:\Code\dockertest\src\server\server.csproj.`

UPDATE 2:
This works fine when I switch to a windows container but not Linux

Comment: When you say `WORKDIR /src` and then you say `COPY src/server/server.csproj src/server`, isn't the `.csproj` going to `src/src/server/` but you are `RUN`ning it as `RUN dotnet restore src/server/server.csproj`?

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa I'm not sure. This was all auto generated, I would assume/hope it would be correct.. but maybe because it's being run on a Linux container the pathing is different?

Comment: I think Docker should take care of the pathing in Linux or Windows. Can you try with  `WORKDIR /src
COPY src/server/server.csproj server/
COPY src/client/client.csproj client/
RUN dotnet restore server/server.csproj`?

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa That appeared to make no difference, but I updated the OP to include an error I noticed in the output window.

Comment: Why is it looking for a Windows' style path if it is done on Linux? You may also want to convert all your text files to unix format by running dos2unix on all of them.

Comment: Do you have `.Net` installed in the container?

Comment: Turns out it was because I was using a `Directory.Build.Targets` file to add some references. Apparently, docker or something downstream doesn't support it

Answer (score 1):

I might be super late to the party,

I just had this problem and the issue was with the "Case" of the project or folder it was in.  For example I got reported from the solution file.

Cannot find "/src/tests/myproject.csproj"

however the folder name was "Tests"    once I fixed this the docker build works fine.

Hope this helps.

b.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I've been trying to figure this out for over an hour now.